# Can't run EMR Hadoop Streaming job with custom executable

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hadoop-streaming, amazon-emr, emr

**Edit:**

Looking at namenode logs, I notice that an exception gets raised periodically. Could it be relevant?

```
2013-04-10 19:23:50,613 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping (IPC Server handler 43 on 9000): got exception trying to get groups for user job_201304101854_0005
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: id: job_201304101854_0005: No such user

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:1037)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.<init>(FSPermissionChecker.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkTraverse(FSNamesystem.java:5201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:2030)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getFileInfo(NameNode.java:850)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1389)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1387)
2013-04-10 19:23:50,614 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping (IPC Server handler 43 on 9000): add job_201304101854_0005 to shell userGroupsCache
2013-04-10 19:23:50,614 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation (IPC Server handler 43 on 9000): No groups available for user job_201304101854_0005
2013-04-10 19:23:55,886 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation (IPC Server handler 46 on 9000): No groups available for user job_201304101854_0005
```

We have produced custom binaries to do map and reduce, tested their correct operation using the common sense "cat file | map | sort | reduce > output" pattern. We made sure to statically compile the binaries to pull in as many dependencies as possible and we have also confirmed that the binaries run on Amazon's EMR AMIs by manually uploading them to the master. If relevant, our language of choice is Haskell and the compilation result is a simple, native, binary executable.

Taking the simplest case:

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input s3n://path/to/input \
    -output s3n://path/to/output \
    -mapper "s3n://path/to/Program map" \
    -reducer "s3n://path/to/Program reduce"
```

The job does start, but it gets stuck at the map 0% phase and doesn't budge. It does not go forward from there and none of the logs seem to indicate anything useful. Each map task gets killed due to 'not reporting back' in 600s. Each mapper shows something like the following as its status, while showing 0% completion:

```
s3n://path/to/file.csv.gz:0+38175575
```

The counters section shows something like 17.5KB read from s3n.

If we now modify the job to the following in order to test:

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input s3n://path/to/input \
    -output s3n://path/to/output \
    -mapper s3n://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py \
    -reducer aggregate
```

then mapper phase finishes 100%, but reducer raises exceptions with:

```
java.io.IOException: exception in uploadSinglePart
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.MultipartUploadOutputStream.uploadSinglePart(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.MultipartUploadOutputStream.close(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat$LineRecordWriter.close(TextOutputFormat.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: exception in putObject
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.storeFile(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy3.storeFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.MultipartUploadOutputStream.uploadSinglePart(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:160)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 8220819721FFE29E, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: Access Denied, S3 Extended Request ID: TekkBZzgaBlK0e8SkoC7bcBsu1w7Nbpy2U7hPCGp5IPrrsqaPTxUg7QQ09xTXRYC
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:619)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:317)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:170)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2943)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.storeFile(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:121)
    ... 20 more
```

The frustrating part is that running hive on the same kind of EMR cluster, for example, seems not to have any problems creating new externally mapped tables, and therefore files, on S3.

Having tried several ideas, I would greatly appreciate it if someone can give us the right direction to get our setup working.

Thank you,
OA

Answer (score 3):

I think it's likely that this is your problem:

```
-mapper "s3n://path/to/Program map"
```

it's very possible that the whitespace is causing you problems. I would probably try building two separate binaries, one for map and one for reduce, that you can call directly as opposed to passing an argument. at least that will help you pinpoint the problem.

Failing that, this smells like an S3 permissioning or mime type issue. I'd check the permissions on your bucket to verify that the credentials you're using for you EMR job will have access to the bucket.

Once you're sure there, I'd check the permissions and properties of the binaries themselves; I have had strange problems when S3 mime types aren't set correctly. For example, here's the wordSplitter info:

```
$ s3cmd info s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py
s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py (object):
File size: 294
Last mod:  Wed, 29 Feb 2012 01:50:25 GMT
MIME type: text/x-python
MD5 sum:   f5b4829658cfbcd5fa5eb32c58163fa8
```

It's possible your binaries have defaulted to a mime type that is somehow impeding execution.

Comment: Thank you. I'm pretty sure the credentials used to launch EMR have full access to the bucket. I checked the mime type using the same command, and I see that it is "MIME type: binary/octet-stream". Is that what we're expecting for a binary executable?

Comment: that mime type looks right to me. I think your problem is the "/Program map" and "/Program reduce" arguments. I edited my post because I think you should try it with no arguments as it's very possible EMR is handling that in a weird way.

Comment: Will try and report back. Does streaming know to do things like "chmod +x Program" before executing? In the meantime, you were right about S3 permissions. The node IAM role needed write access to that bucket. So that piece is fine now.

Comment: for vanilla hadoop streaming you need to make sure your file is has executable permissions, but I would assume that EMR would handle this for you, as there's no way to do that on S3 that I am aware.

Comment: kudos for using haskell, btw :).

Comment: Strange that when I use the wordcount python script, the mapper status quickly changes to "RW 5000/100000" or something similar. When I use the binary, I keep seeing something like "s3n://path/to/file.csv.gz:0+38175575".

Comment: The separate executable didn't solve the issue, unfortunately. It is still stuck at the same place :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27976/discussion-between-paul-sanwald-and-ozataman)